# how to validate divisions having toggle like one have to fill all information before going to 2nd division

Tags: jquery, validation, slidetoggle

I have used toggle in 3 divisions with jquery.

When we click on first div it will show the popup having contact details, with the 2nd having additional details, finally the 3rd will show payment details.

Now i want to apply validation on div that the client can go to 2nd division only after filling the 1st division details successfully and likewise for the 3rd.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery Form

> Wizard

Like this

[Demo](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Form-Wizard-with-Input-Validation-Simple-Form/)

Comment: Download this source http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Simple-jQuery-Form-Wizard-with-Input-Validation-Simple-Form.html